# Autodesk Forge View Cube

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

I have a markup extension for forge viewer, and i want to change the models position with coordinates in markup svg. I already got the coordinates and tried to change, but nothing.

i got the coordinates with this code

```
    let svg = document.querySelector('svg');
    let box = svg.getAttribute('viewBox').split(' ');
```

and tried to change position with this

```
viewer.autocam.camera.position.setX(parseFloat(box[0]));
viewer.autocam.camera.position.setY(parseFloat(box[1]));
viewer.autocam.camera.position.setZ(parseFloat(box[2]));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is changing the camera's position... Are you trying to change the **position of the model** or that of the **camera**? ...

To change the position of the camera try `navigation.setView`:

```
const position = new THREE.vector3(x,y,z)
const target = NOP_VIEWER.navigation.getTarget()
viewer.nativation.setView(position, target)
```

**EDIT**

To translate (move) the entire model try translate all the fragments:

```
const total = NOP_VIEWER.model.getInstanceTree().fragList.length //fragment is 0 indexed and increments by 1 so basically iterate from 0 to length -1 

//...
for (int i=0,i<total,i++){
const fragProxy = NOP_VIEWER.impl.getFragmentProxy(NOP_VIEWER.model,i);

                const position = new THREE.Vector3(
                    target.x - fragProxy.offset.x,
                    target.y - fragProxy.offset.y,
                    target.z - fragProxy.offset.z);

                fragProxy.position = position;

                fragProxy.updateAnimTransform();

}
            viewer.impl.sceneUpdated(true);
```

See this sample [here](https://github.com/apprentice3d/ForgeViewerExtensions/blob/master/assets/js/extensions/TransformTool.js#L88) for more details.

Comment: No, I try to change position of the model, but positions i get from markup svg.How can i do it?

Comment: Thank you very much!!